# newpax error with pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages, pax

I am attempting to preserve hyperlinks while combining several PDFs into a single PDF with a TOC. `newpax` seems to be the way, but I can't compile with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying colours by name
\definecolor{htmlblue}{HTML}{0000EE}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref} % Required for links
\hypersetup{
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=htmlblue,
    pdftitle={$title$},
    pdfauthor={$author$},
}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}

\usepackage{newpax}

\title{$title$}
\author{$author$}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
 
\bigskip

\tableofcontents

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{First PDF}
\includepdf[pages=-]{letter.pdf}
 
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Second PDF}
\includepdf[pages=-]{article.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Package newpax Error: PDF resource management code not found!
(newpax)                newpage will no work..
```

I'm having trouble finding other example usages with `newpax`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need `\DocumentMetadata{}` before \documentclass.

Comment: I just added that and get a new error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \DocumentMetadata`

Comment: get a newer LaTeX.

Comment: I shall. Is there a workaround before I do that? I've got Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021). Have a deadline tomorrow and don't want to mess anything up...

Comment: Well you can try the old method to load the pdfmanagement: `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}`. But it is naturally a bit daring to start to use such a new package one day before the deadlline.

Comment: Success, many thanks! I learned about pdfpages' inability to preserve hyperlinks at the last minute the hard way... will update my LaTeX this week.